# Render form if user_id equal to user's post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render a form only if the user_id is equal to the user's post. So that whenever a user tries to visit another profile the form does not show up.

That's the current code for the rendering:

```
<% if current_user.id  == @post.user_id %>
    <%= render 'posts/form' %>
<% end %>
```

It doesn't hide the form whenever I try to visit another profile so I tried doing an each loop and it worked but with one small bug. If the user doesn't have any posts yet, the form does not appear at all.

The each loop:

```
<% @posts.take(1).each do |p| %>
    <% if current_user.id  == p.user_id %>
        <%= render 'posts/form' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @post = Post.new
  end


  def show

  end


  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

P.S: I made the form to render in the profile view and not the index's.
Profile controller:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    def profile
        @posts = Post.where( "user_id = ?", User.find_by_id(params[:id]) )
        @post = Post.new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you should be evaluating whether the `@user.id` is the same as `current_user`:

```
#app/views/profiles/show.html.erb
<%= render "posts/form" if current_user.id == @user.id %>

#app/controllers/profile_controller.rb
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user  = User.find params[:id]
        @posts = @user.posts
        @post  = @posts.new
    end
end
```

---

This type of functionality is known as `authorization`, which means you'd be better off using [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to get it to work more efficiently:

```
#Gemfile 
gem "cancancan"

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id
  end
end

#app/views/profiles/show.html.erb
<%= render "posts/form" if can? :create, @post %>
```

The above should work considering `@post` will have `@user.id`, rather than `current_user.id` as its foreign key.

Comment: undefined method `can?`

Comment: Did you add the cancancan gem?

Comment: Sorry in my haste to write an answer, I forgot that `current_user` is passed to the `can?` method by default! (see update)